# How do I get faction ships?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm playing Elite: Dangerous and doing my best to do the missions (Mining is literally the worst). I get that there's a reputation section that shows how much a faction likes you, but I'm not sure how to determine what rank I am. This is irrelevant if I have no idea how to GET that rank, so this leads me to my question.

**How do I get the Imperial/Federation ships in Elite: Dangerous?**

Comment: I haven't played in a very long time, so this might've changed... but raising faction rank is simply do missions for that faction. You'll eventually get rank up missions (a quick delivery or kill) and that's that.

Comment: Mining is the best! Anyway, [here is a related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282102/sol-permits-for-dummies) that is specifically concerning gaining Federation ranks, but the answer applies to most any faction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Imperial/Federation stations, there are often **missions** that instead of providing money, provide rank advancement.

To get these missions to show up, just play major faction oriented missions to gain reputation with that faction (Minor factions are irrelevant at this point). Eventually some missions will show up. They can even show up at independent stations, just wherever faction missions are available.

Then your faction rank will show up under your reputation tab.

Beware than gaining these ranks can be a bit of a grind if you want to get the higher end ships such as the Federal Corvette, or the imperial cutter.

Comment: It should be noted that promotion missions don't always appear at faction stations, it can often be "luck" getting them to show at times.